# How to put kafkaJson data to external MySQL db in Flink1.5

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am new to Flink and need to stream Json data from Kafka to MySQL table through Flink. Not able to transfer the data in an external MYSQL instance. Here is what I have tried. Any help will be appreciated.
The field includes timestamp: String, merchantId: String, cid: String, uid: String, sessionId: String, event: String, eventType: String, ip: String, refUrl: String, referrer: String

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment()
val tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)
val prop = new Properties()
prop.setProperty("zookeeper.connect","")
prop.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
prop.setProperty("group.id", "test")
prop.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
val output: DataStream[String] = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer011[String]("TQBQTEST_USER_AUG_2018", new serialization.SimpleStringSchema(), prop))
val finalTable = tEnv.registerDataStream("User",output)
env.execute()
```

Comment: Wondering why your using Flink rather than Kafka Connect JDBC sink

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

(1) You may want to upgrade to Flink 1.6, as the support for connecting the Flink's Table/SQL APIs to external systems has been significantly enhanced in this release.

(2) You'll have an easier time if you use the appropriate Kafka Table Source and the JDBC Table Sink. You'll find the documentation for [version 1.6 here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/table/connect.html), and for [version 1.5 here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/table/sourceSinks.html).